# Multiprocessing iteration without repeating duplicates in Python

Tags: python, iteration, unique, python-multiprocessing

In python, I have a large list of numbers (~0.5 billion items) with some duplicates in it, for example:

```
[1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6]
```

I want to apply a function over these numbers to create a dictionary, keyed by the number, giving the function result. So if the function is simply (say) `lambda x: x*10`, I want a dictionary like:

```
{1:10, 2:20, 3:30, 4:40, 5:50, 6:60}
```

The thing is, I want to use the Python multiprocessing module to do this (I don't care in what order the functions are run), and I don't really want to make the list of numbers unique beforehand: I'd prefer to check when iterating over the numbers whether there's a duplicate, and if so, not add the calculation to the multiprocessing pool or queue.

So should I use something like multiprocessing.Pool.imap_unordered for this, and check for previously visited iterators, e.g.:

```
import multiprocessing
import itertools
import time

def f(x):
    print(x)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return x, x*10.0

input = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6]
result = {}

def unique_everseen(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element not in result:
            result[element] = None  # Mark this result as being processed
            yield element

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
    for k, v in pool.imap_unordered(f, unique_everseen(input)):
        result[k]=v
```

I ask, as it seems a little hacky using the `result` dictionary to also check whether we have visited this value before (I've done this to save having to create a separate set of half a billion items just to check if they are dups). Is there a more pythonic way to do this, perhaps adding the items to a Queue or something? I'm not used multiprocessing much before, so perhaps I'm doing this wrong, and e.g. opening myself up to race conditions?

Comment: Convert the list to a set first, then iterate over the set? input = set(input)

Comment: you can use a `multiprocessing.Manager.dict()` if you want to make sure that there are no race conditions/concurrent dict accesses. The fact that your code works makes me believe that `unique_everseen` is only called in the main process, so you're safe.

Comment: @Spencer - since this is a big list (and it's actually a list of tuples: I simplified it for the question), I'd prefer not to unique-ify it beforehand, as I mentioned in the question: it seems more efficient to do it on-the-fly.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre wouldn't that end up virtually serializing this process? If you're locking the dictionary then the speed benefit of multiprocessing seems like it would be negligible.

Comment: @user2667066 I'm certainly not an expert at multiprocessing but I don't see a way to optimize this without first reducing your list. Otherwise (unless I'm wrong) no matter what you're going to have to lock a shared resource to compare to, which will just end up virtually serializing your code. In my experience multiprocessing simple operations like this is best done without sharing resources.

Comment: Oh and Jean-FrancoiseFabre is correct that you're going to want to use the multiprocessing dict() instead of a regular dict.

Comment: @Spencer - what I'm doing at the moment *seems* OK to me, as I think the `unique_everseen` function is called outside of the parallelised part (indeed, the imap function never gets to see the duplicate iterators, as far as I can see, although by using a queue I suppose I could make 100% sure of that). But I guess my way is simply an alternative to making the initial list unique.